# cross application (authentication) issue using react.js, spring, tomcat 8

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, tomcat

My team is rewriting an existing web application that has a react.js front-end and springboot backend.  In addition, The original (legacy) app is written in java (tomcat 8 & struts) and that will continue to be used for some parts of the site until a later date when we will complete the rewrite. All 3 endpoints are on the same domain in the following format:  react.js (mysite.mydomain.com), spring (mysiteapp.mydomain.com), and legacy (mysite.mydomain.com/old). All 3 apps are hosted on the same server, but the application urls all route through our F5, so nothing is pointing to localhost.  We did this to use the same SSL certificate across the three apps.  The new and legacy apps use the same database.  We are trying to make cross app calls between the new and old app.  When we make the cross app calls, we want the user session to be maintained between them without them having to log in twice.  We have not been able to get this to work.  In our latest attempt to authenticate the user to both apps simultaneously, we are using ajax to sign the user into legacy with the same credentials.  We are getting the following error back from the legacy tomcat application:  HTTP Status 403 Invalid CSRF token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.  The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. We are stumped at this point and out of ideas.  Code can be provided on request, but we are looking for the best approach to how to implement this and not as much locked on this path described above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: better to add image (architectur) on ur question